# Xamarin OnActivityResult not called (again)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Im having this so common problem.

My app has three activities. In MainActivity, the user touches a button and the second activity is launched where a list of entities is shown. When the user clicks one entity in the list a third activity is launched where item data can be edited.

Here is the part of the code which matters:

MainActivity:

```
  [Activity(Label = "MainActivity", MainLauncher = true)]
  public class MainActivity : Activity
  {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
      ...
    {

    public void transitionToSecondActivity()
    {
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        ...Add data to bundle.
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
        intent.PutExtras(data);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
  }
```

SecondActivity: (Where onActivityResult is not called)

```
  [Activity(Label = "SecondActivity")]
  public class SecondActivity : Activity
  {
    private static int EDIT_ACTIVITY = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
      PopulateScreen();
    }

    private void TransitionToEditEntity(int Id) {        

      var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ThirdActivity));
      Bundle data = new Bundle();
      ...Add data to bundle.
      intent.PutExtras(data);
      StartActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_ACTIVITY);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Android.App.Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        // This is not called.
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == EDIT_ACTIVITY)
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() => PopulateScreen());
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

ThirdActivity: After finishing this activity, i would have to refresh the list if the item was succesfully edited. FinishSuccess() is called when the item is edited succesfully (just in case you didnt notice).

```
  [Activity(Label = "ThirdActivity")]
  public class ThirdActivity : Activity 
  {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
      ...
    }

    private void FinishSuccess() {        
      SetResult(Result.Ok, new Intent());
      Finish();
    }      
  }
```

Notes:
1) If I change StartActivity in MainActivity to StartActivityForResult the result is the same (dont work).
2) If I start ThirdActivity from MainActivity, OnActivityResult() is called on MainActivity after ThirActivity finish.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had a similar problem, spent half a day on it, and a clean and rebuild did the trick in the end. Worth a shot, just in case it's the same bug I had.

Comment: did you try removing `base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` so it doesn't call baes and changing `SetResult(Result.Ok, new Intent());` for `SetResult(Result.Ok);` ?

Comment: I spent hours trying different solutions like the ones suggested by @fmaccaroni. Finally a simple clean and build did the job.